# Angular's module optional configuration

Tags: angularjs

Now I'm configuring my module with constant and then inject it. 
F.e.

```
angular.module('myModule').constant('myConf', {templatesUrl: '/static/templates'})
```

or sometimes

```
angular.module('myModule').constant('myConf', {templatesUrl: '/static/otherTemplates'})
```

But I have to define it every time even I don't want to modify default config.

How can I add **optional** configuration for the module? I can't skip defining it in html now — injector will throw error because `myConf` will be undefined.

It's not about defining `constant` — I'm looking for any ways to optionally provide some initial values to module

Like I have config

```
{
    'var1': 'value1',
    'var2': 'value2',
    'var3': 'value3',
}
```

I want to overwrite some properties if it's possible but don't touch other. And after I somehow assign var2 to 'newValue' I'll have

```
{
    'var1': 'value1',
    'var2': 'newValue',
    'var3': 'value3',
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @JBNizet f.e. I have some default values like urls. Sometimes I need to overwrite them.

Comment: And where are these default values defined? How do you overwrite them? Please edit your question and provide more details, and example code.

Comment: Now I'm using constant as I said before. So I have to copy-paste it on every page I'm using it.

Comment: No, you don't. Why would you have to do that? And AngularJS is for single page applications, so you have a single page anyway. Once again, provide more details.

Comment: You're wrong. Angular is not for SPA only. A lot of people are using it as components on html page that being rendered on server.

Comment: OK. That would be an atypical usage. So, would you care describing your situation in the question? We're not extra-lucid wizards.

Comment: @JBNizet added. Better now?

Comment: Better, yes. Do you want to be able to replace the whole config by a new one, or to be able to overwrite some properties only?

Comment: @JBNizet Some properties is better, but if I'll be able to set whole config not on every page I'll be happy too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this idea below?

**In html**

```
<script src="default.config.module.js"></script>
<script src="my.module.js"></script>
```

**In default.config.module.js**
(You could define default values in single common file.)

```
angular.module('configModule', [])
.constant('myConf', {val1: 'value1', val2: 'value2', val3: 'value3'})
```

**In my.module.js**
(You could override specific properties you like)

```
angular.module('myModule', ['configModule'])
.config(function(myConf){
    myConf.val2 = 'newValue';
})
```

[jsfiddle is here.](https://jsfiddle.net/yazaki/7r5pu2w5/)

Comment: Do you mean `value` function would be better than `constant` function? If you decide to use `value` function, you need to use `run` function instead of `config` function.